# Android Ble scanning in the background slow

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app that has a background service continuously running and uses iBeacons to alert the app when it's near a Ble beacon which the user can place his phone near and read information from the Ble beacon.

I'm trying to proximity check and start the app when the RSSI from the Bluetooth callback is lower than a certain value and it's working fast on devices with OS lower than Android 7.
**But on Android 7 and higher i'm only getting Bluetooth callbacks with a 5 second delay which is too slow. Why is there so much difference and is there any way to speed up the callback frequency**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have changed it so that in the background, it runs with scan parameters with lower duty. That is, 500 ms window every 5 seconds if I'm not mistaken. I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

In my opinion 500 ms/5 seconds is quite a bad choice. 50 ms every 500 ms would be better...